# Rails 3: Why integer field is not validated against regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

`Job` model has an integer `job_price` field:

```
class CreateJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :jobs do |t|
      ...
      t.integer "job_price"
      ...
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

I would like to display an error message if user types strings in the `job_price` field, so I added the following validation:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base 
  validates_format_of :job_price, :with => /\A\d{0,10}\z/, 
                      :message => "^Job Price must be valid"
  ...
end
```

However, it seems like the validation passes even when I type strings.

Any ideas why ?

---

**Note**

I had to add `:value => @job.job_price_before_type_cast` here:

```
f.text_field(:job_price, :maxlength => 10, 
             :value => @job.job_price_before_type_cast)
```

because, otherwise, if I was typing `abc5`, for example, and then submit the form, Rails was converted it to `5` (I guess because `job_price` is defined as integer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could ensure it's an integer and in a range:

```
validates_numericality_of :myfield, :only_integer => true
validates_inclusion_of :myfield, :in => 0..9999999999
```

Comment: I'm finding that numeric values given for integer-type attributes seem to have already been rounded to integers prior to validation, so fractional entries are treated as valid, even when the `:only_integer => true` option is used.

Answer (score 3):

Rails 3 way would be:

```
validates :myfield, :numericality => { only_integer: true }
validates :myfield, :inclusion => { :in => 1..10000 }
```

Answer (score 2):

ActiveModel does have a built-in validation method for integers.

[validates_numericality_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_numericality_of)

Hopefully will behave how you want it to.